# Unpack file compressed in .txz and .tar with one command

Tags: shell, tar, compression

I have a file compressed in *.txz. After unpacking it I received a *.tar file. Is there any way to unpack it twice with one command? I mean unpack file (*.tar).txz with one command?

For know I'm do it like this:

```
xz -d file.txz
tar xvf file.tar
```

But I wonder if there is nicer way.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
xz -d < file.tar.xz | tar xvf -
```

That's the same as with any compressed archive. You should *never* have to create an uncompressed copy of the original file.

Some `tar` implementations like recent versions of GNU `tar` have builtin options to call `xz` by themselves.

With GNU `tar` or `bsdtar`:

```
tar Jxvf file.tar.xz
```

Though, if you've got a version that has `-J`, chances are it will detect `xz` files automatically, so:

```
tar xvf file.tar.xz
```

will suffice.

If your GNU or BSD `tar` is too old to support `xz` specifically, you may be able to use the `--use-compress-program` option:

```
tar --use-compress-program=xz -xvf file.tar.gz
```

One of the advantages of having `tar` invoke the compressor utility is that it  is able to report the failure of it in its exit  status.

Note: if the `tar.xz` archive has been created with `pixz`, `pixz` may have added a `tar` index to it, which allows extracting files individually without having to uncompress the whole archive:

```
pixz -x path/to/file/in/archive < file.tar.xz | tar xvf -
```

Comment: I have to use this one: tar --use-compress-program=xz -xvf file.tar.gz

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This should be the way to go `tar Jxvf file.txz`

Comment: Yes, for modern `tar`, you can [use `-J` or `--xz`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar).

Answer (score 5):

Unpacking is probably not the right terminology. You can *decompress* with `xz` and *untar* with `tar`.

The manual page for GNU `tar` (`man tar`, GNU tar is default on Debian) specifies that you can use:

```
-I, --use-compress-program PROG
      filter through PROG (must accept -d)
```

and `xz` supports the `-d` option, so you can use:

```
tar --use-compress-program xz xvf file.txz
```

What is far less clear from the man page is that `-xz` and `-J` are shorthands for `--use-compress-program xz` or `-I xz`.

And what is not specified at all in the man page is that you can just do

```
tar xvf file.txz
```

in GNU tar and that it will recognise the tar file as being compressed with `xz`.